# Cannot restart apache after installing mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache2, web-development

I am trying to learn python web application development using Ubuntu 12.04. I have installed apache2 and enabled mod_wsgi using the command `sudo a2enmod wsgi`. Now when i try to restart the apache2 it shows the error

```
   apache2: Syntax error on line 210 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/wsgi.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so-2.7 into server: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

I have checked the location `usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so-2.7` and this file is really present there. I am very new to python development. Please help.

UPDATE:
I am updating my question to include Sylvain Pineau's susggestion.
They Python 2.7 is already installed. When i run the command given by Sylvain Pineau i got

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libpython2.7 is already the newest version.
libpython2.7 set to manually installed.
python2.7 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Update: I have reinstalled python 2.7. it was broken. Thank Sylvain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

I'd suggest to install python2.7 (both the interpreter and the library):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpython2.7 python2.7
```

To find which package(s) provide `libpython2.7.so.1.0` I used this [query](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libpython2.7.so.1.0&mode=exactfilename&suite=precise&arch=any).

Comment: python 2.7 is already installed. See the updated question

Comment: my libpython2.7.so.1.0 is located in /usr/lib. when i run ls-l it showed in red color. Is there anything to do with that?

Comment: It should be light blue, red means a broken link. Try to reinstall both packages using `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpython2.7 python2.7`

Comment: Cool. Good luck with your web development